# Hide an absolute centered div by resizing the viewport

Tags: html, css, height, viewport, absolute

I have a problem related to my centered div.

I would like that when the height of the viewport is resized, the div goes under viewport instead to ascend at the top of the screen.

[Here is the positioned div without viewport resizing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhZnR.png)

[Here is the positioned div with viewport resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skw2G.png)

[Here is what i would like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNAE1.jpg)

```
 main {
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    }

    .container {
        background: red;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);


    <body>

      <main>

         <div class="container-div">
            <h2>My div that i want to hide</h2>

         </div>

      </main>

    </body>
```

I hope this is understandable enough.. Thank you !

Comment: Could you include your HTML? Should the answer be CSS-HTML-only? Do you want the div to be completely hidden when the window is being resized, or push the div under the viewport in such way you could only see the top of it? This question needs more details.

Comment: The answer can include JS as well. I want the div is completely hide and not pushed to the top. Sorry for not clear question !

Answer (score 0):

We can add an `onresize` attribute to the body, which will call for `myFunction` on window's resize:

```js
function myFunction() {
   document.getElementsByClassName("container-div")[0].style.display = "none"
}
```

```html
<body onresize="myFunction()">

      <main>

         <div class="container-div">
            <h2>My div that i want to hide</h2>

         </div>

      </main>

    </body>
```

P.S: You can see it works as when opening the snippet for the first time, Stack-Overflow has a scrolling animation which does include some resizing of the snippet window, and so the div disappears as expected. Don't let that confuse you ;)